# Web scraping Mechanize in Ruby producing different html to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm relatively new to Ruby and Mechanize but i'm having some difficulty with an asp website

```
URL: http://www.adecco.co.uk/careercentre/job-search-results.aspx?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=&pdx=1


agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.adecco.co.uk/careercentre/job-search-results.aspx?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=&pdx=1')
puts page.body
```

I was working through the examples from the Mechanize website the thing is the HTML I get back via Mechanize is very different from what I get using view source in my browser, I need the finished HTML?

**Update**

I'm not quite sure what to do here since the problem is actually with the fact that the page renders the content using jquery afterwards so i've ended up using Selenium  to grab the page with the correct html, neither of these answers are actually wrong so i've upvoted both, but neither actually solve the problem?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code,

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.adecco.co.uk/careercentre/job-search-results.aspx?kws=&pstc=&cty=&prvnm=&pdx=1')

document = Nokogiri::HTML(page.content)
puts document
```

Comment: You don't need to include nokogiri separately or do anything with Nokogiri::HTML. Mechanize does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because the website handle different user agents differently, you can set the user agent same as your browser as follows

```
a = Mechanize.new
a.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
```

you can any value of these

```
AGENT_ALIASES = {
  'Windows IE 6' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
  'Windows IE 7' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
  'Windows Mozilla' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4b) Gecko/20030516 Mozilla Firebird/0.6',
  'Mac Safari' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10',
  'Mac FireFox' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6',
  'Mac Mozilla' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X Mach-O; en-US; rv:1.4a) Gecko/20030401',
  'Linux Mozilla' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624',
  'Linux Firefox' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.1) Gecko/20100122 firefox/3.6.1',
  'Linux Konqueror' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3; Linux)',
  'iPhone' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C28 Safari/419.3',
  'Mechanize' => "WWW-Mechanize/#{VERSION} (http://rubyforge.org/projects/mechanize/)"
}
```

the above list exists here 
https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize.rb#L115